# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android Studio - Java/Kotlin and Visual Studio - Xamarin

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin.android, wear-os, wearables

I am wanting to debug and install my application on a physical clock.

First I tried to create the application in Xamarin.Android, I finished the application and it worked very well in an emulator, but when I tried to send to the device, the following error appeared:

> ADB0010: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be >installed in /data/app/AppXamarinWear.AppXamarinWear-1: Package >AppXamarinWear.AppXamarinWear requires unavailable shared library >com.google.android.wearable; failing!]
>     em Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String >output, String packageName) na >E:\A_work\1824\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputP>arsing.cs:linha 341
>     em Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.>>b__0(Task`1 t) na >E:\A\_work\1824\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:li>nha 753
>     em System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>     em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()            0

Then I created an empty project in AndroidStudio, just created the project, did not change any line of code, and tried to run the application on the device, so I got the following error:

> Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session 1131471407 >with command cmd package install-commit 1131471407. Error: >INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in >/data/app/br.pinheiros.weardebug7-1: Package br.pinheiros.weardebug7 requires >unavailable shared library com.google.android.wearable; failing!.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing >version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

I understood that the two solutions are bringing the same error, something with Google Api, I have already changed all the developer settings in Wear.

Model: Zeblaze Thor 4 Pro

Comment: What happens if you remove this line from your AndroidManfiest file    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" />. Also what android version does your watch have?

Comment: In Xamarin: installed the app, but gave Initialize () error asking to include the library,

In Android Studio: installed the app, opened the app, but closed in the same second without any error message, then reinsert the library, but this time I put it inside <application> the result was the same, install -> open - > close; 
In Android Studio was a big breakthrough if you can help more

Comment: What's the version of OS on the watch

Comment: Dude, I got it working, I put the library inside the <Application> tag and I changed the WearableActivity to Activity page interface and it worked!

Comment: Dude that's awesome, keep it up! Also, put your answer in the Answer box below and mark it as correct, so others are able to benefit as well